# Angular 2 impure pipe vs directive performance

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, ngx-translate

I am looking at the `ngx-translates` two ways of giving the translate input.

1. Either as a pipe `{{'messageId' | translate}}`
2. OR as a directive `<span [translate]="'messageId'">`

The pipe is an Impure pipe that can handle the translation and any async loading of text. The downside to this approach that I see is that the this gets triggered every time that the digest cycles runs.

The other approach would be using the directive. In which case, we can control when the methods gets fired by using Events or Observables. This method would reduce the unnecessary updates.

But since directives manipulating the DOM, my question is will the directive approach make things slower overall? Also, is there a way to measure the performance of one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpolation in Angular are syntactic sugar over property bindings. As explained in the documentation, these two are same

```
<p><span>"{{title}}" is the <i>interpolated</i> title.</span></p>
<p>"<span [innerHTML]="title"></span>" is the <i>property bound</i> title.</p>
```

So if you see benefits of property binding, go for it.

Comment: The problem is, the `[translate]` directive does more than just binding. It still has to write to the DOM. 
`node.textContent = this.key ? node.currentValue : node.originalContent.replace(key, node.currentValue);
                this._ref.markForCheck();` 

This is used in their [source code](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/src/translate.directive.ts), would this be any slower than property binding?

Comment: I believe the interpolation too needs to do the same as the use the same binding infrastructure.